# Language C - Get the Process owner

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

I have to use the EXEC family to find the process owned (the user) and write it in a file.

CODE:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d", getpid());

if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      else if (pid == 0)
        {
          dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);
          dup2(fd,STDERR_FILENO);

          // function that Write in the file
          fdprintf(fd, "\n%s %s%d secondes %s\n", adornment, toShow, sec, adornment);

          if (execlp("ps", "u", buffer, NULL) == -1)
            show_err("Exelp Error\n");
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      else
        {
          wait(NULL);
          fdprintf(fd, "%s %s%d secondes %s\n", adornment, toShow, sec, adornment);
          close(fd);
        }
```

any help is appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: What OS?  I am guessing a unix flavour from your first execlp output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I user EXECVE...
It works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is the [thedailywtf](http://thedailywtf.com/) equivalent of [`getuid(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getuid.html). If you want to get the login name, you can use [`getpwuid(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html).

Comment: In fact, i've to use exec... so no :)

Answer (score 0):

getppid()

get parent pid, check the man pages for more info

```
pid_t parent_pid = getppid();
```